# magento 2 custom attributes value frontend return No value of select

Tags: magento-2.1, custom-options, frontend, product-list, list.phtml

I have a problem in retrieving the value of **custom attribute** of **type select**, it returns a value No
[image]

I try this code in

list.phtml:

```
 <span class="product_badge_value">
 <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ print_r($_product->getResource()->getAttribute('product_badge')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product)); ?>
  </span>
```

Comment: It's look like your code is right. try echo instead of print_r()

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

After adding custom attribute, you need to reindex and clear cache as follows.

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Then try again.

Comment: same problem it doesn't work.

Comment: Same poblm :/<span class="product_badge_value">
                                <?php
                                $badge=$_product->getResource()->getAttribute('product_badge')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
                                /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $badge ;
                                ?>
                            </span>

Answer (score 0):

This is the property/bug of Magento custom attribute where it will create records in  eav table only after we save that particular product manually. Otherwise the attribute returns a NULL value. So if you need to get the value for product_badge attribute you need to save that particular product and check from the front end.

Answer (score -1):

You have to set yes in:

*Stores -> Attributes -> Product (edit attribute) -> Storefront properties -> Visible on Catalog Pages on StoreFront*

[image]